# php query save in db. when get then we want exucute?

Tags: php, mysql

one code which save in db:

> "
>   height="150" width="120"/>

When we get this and set on textarea then we want this query{which save in db} executed.

Comment: Sorry this code we save in db:<div>
< ? php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company_details");
  while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
 $company_id = $rows['company_id'];
}
? >
<img src="< ? php echo $company_id ? >" height="150" width="120"/>
</div>

Comment: Paste your properly formatted code into the question, then use the `{ }` tool in the SO editor to mark it as code. Don't use the quotation tool for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this i get answer from other.

if php code is save in db and after retrieve code will not executed. so we save our php code in a .php file. and file name save in db. and when we use this code [by include file.] php code is executed. 
Thanks.